# How to Implement a Constructor?

Tags: vb.net, constructor

```
Module Module1
    Class Arithmetical
        Public Function Subtract(ByVal a As Integer, ByVal b As Integer)
            Return a - b
        End Function
    End Class

    Sub Main()
        Dim objArithmetical As New Arithmetical()
        Console.WriteLine(objArithmetical.Subtract(80, 27))
        Console.ReadKey()
    End Sub
End Module
```

How would I implement a constructor into this? I am new to this coding and language(VB.NET) Anything would be greatly appreciated.

Thank You

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need to implement a constructor, you can use the code below :

```
Public Sub New()

End Sub
```

For more info, you can find some documentation here : [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/2z08e49e(v=vs.90).aspx) or [DotNetPerls](http://www.dotnetperls.com/class-vbnet)

Hope it helps !